# Is there a text editor which opens a DXF with code folding?

Tags: ascii, cad, folding, dxf, code-folding

### Use case

1. I am working on CAD files, doing lots of basic coordinate geometry
   operations on basic entities (`3dpoly`s and `arc`s are as
   complicated as it gets).
2. At the moment I am using [`LIST`](https://help.bricsys.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006623554-List) and manipulating the output in
   Excel, but I am looking for improvements to my workflow. Naturally
   autolisp would be my first port of call, but I hope I don't have to
   justify why I don't want it.
3. It seems that the next step for me is to get a feel/basic
   understanding for the structure of DXF files. Whenever I handle
   a new type of ASCII file, I start by opening it in a text editor. I tend to
   find that either notepad++ or geany have code folding by default and
   I can easily get a feel for the structure of the file, which bits I
   need etc.
4. DXF must be the first type of file I have seen which doesn't have
   code folding by default in notepad++. The [DXF spec](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf) at 200+
   pages is not exactly a quick and easy read.

### Solution desired

I am looking for a text editor with [code folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding) for DXF files.

Comment: Have you tried Notepad++?

Comment: Thanks. I hope you noticed this in the question: "4. DXF (...) doesn't have code folding by default in notepad++". I tried searching for a DXF User-Defined Language for notepad++ but couldn't find one. I'm considering asking on a cad forum but I'm still looking for an answer how long I should wait before cross posting.

Comment: Ooops. I missed that. Sorry. I think your challenge is that a DXF file is essentially a number / value pair repetatively in a stacked document. I don't know then. Sorry.